# my render when i click render it shows 1 image only (not render image normal render)

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, rigid-body-simulation

but the render doesn't work all it shows is 1 image and I don't know how to import a .blend here iv tried going and messing with scene settings rigid body world iv tried cycles and none of it work. I have watched countless videos read countless forums and reddits but none have my answer to why when i render it only shows 1 image and im talking about the render button top left when i click it it does its thing but only shows 1 image instead of the animation made by the rigid bodys in the animation tab that works fine but when i click render top left it shows 1 image [image]

Comment: You're hitting "Render Animation", correct? - I did that with your file and it rendered the animation just fine.

Comment: Not sure what "Render button" you're talking about? It works fine for me and creates a Mpeg file as expected when I choose Render > Render Animation from the menu or use Ctrl F12. You aren't seeing an error message in the middle of the bottom status bar are you? If so have you set the output path to a valid file path on the R/H Output Properties tab under 'Output'?

Comment: You watched "countless" videos and read "countless" forums...? I'm sure you must have missed something there. Make sure you have set a valid path for your file, and as John asked, what "render button"? At the top left there is no "button" for rendering, there is only a menu entry, and clicking on it you have different options, the first is _Render Image_, the second is _Render Animation_. If you don't click there, nothing will be rendered at all. As mentioned above, on my computer I can render the animation without problems (after adjusting the output path to a valid target on my drive).